# Studying European legislation after Brexit

Tags: academia

I am reading the book ["Legal Skills" by Emily Finch and Stefan Fafinski](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198831277). I reached the section on EU legislation. Although this book is a new edition, it was written when the UK was still a member of the European Union.

Should I skip sections pertaining to EU legislation? If so, which ones? I recently began self-teaching law. Therefore, there is no syllabus or professor I ought to follow.

Comment: Ask your professor.

Comment: This question is unanswerable. We don't know which book you are reading, and we don't know the syllabus of the class you are taking. It is not even clear that "legal skills" is the title of the book or just the topic.

Comment: @IñakiViggers the book is by Emily finch and stefan fafinski. ISBN:978-0-19-883127-3. Though I am studing law, I am not a student, therefore there is no syllabus or professor. I am highly involved in law, though I have the entry requirements for studing law, it is not practical to study it. But this should not be a problem. I know from experience from studying in other universities (Newcastle and cambridge) in the biomedical feild, which accourding to this book is very similar in structure to law degree, that mostly how well you do in your studies is linked to the student input. I got 1st

Answer (score 1):

Most EU regulations have been turned into UK law. I read there is an estimated 10,000 EU regulations which are automatically law in every country, and about 90% were adopted as Uk law unchanged, with another 10 percent requiring small changes to the law text to make sense for the UK.

So a book about UK regulations would be better, but in principle these regulations still affect everyday life in the uk.

Comment: This answer is basically correct, but its relevance is more limited than one might assume.  Any EU regulations that were automatically applicable in the UK and were therefore not written into domestic law will have ceased to apply on January 1st, 2021.  Many of the domestic laws that gave force to EU directives will have been repealed as of that date (for example, the Immigration (EEA) Regulations 2016).

Comment: @phoog That is [not correct](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2018/16/section/3). All EU law (including regulations) remain part of UK law unless and until specifically repealed.

Comment: @JBentley thanks.  I was not aware of that, mainly because I was most closely following immigration law, which was the implementation of a directive and which was of course promptly explicitly modified.

Comment: It's mostly a matter of sheer numbers. 10,000 regulations, if they all just disappeared, that would be chaos. And there's not time to make meaningful changes. And many are not controversial at all. The changes are for regulations like "All baby pushchairs imported into the EU must ..." which would be pointless as a UK law, and gets changed to "All baby pushchairs imported into the UK must...".

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not skip the sections on EU law.

When the UK [gave notice to withdraw from the EU](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2017/9), Parliament was cognitive of the fact that you can't simply repeal decades worth of law in one fell swoop without causing all sorts of chaos and uncertainty in the legal system.

So, pursuant to sections [2 to 7 of the European Union (Withdrawal) Act 2018](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2018/16/crossheading/retention-of-existing-eu-law), they provided that EU law would remain applicable in the UK after the implementation period, subject to some specific rules and exceptions (which I suggest you familiarise yourself with by reading those sections of the Act).

In this way Parliament is free to take its time to pick and choose which specific laws they want to repeal in the coming years / decades.

One important consequence, pursuant to [section 6](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2018/16/section/6), is the rules of binding precedent have changed in relation to decisions of the European Court, particularly as they concern the Supreme Court.

In summary: you must still learn EU law, but you would be advised to purchase a very recently updated book which takes account of the rules post-implementation period.

Comment: On top of that, some immigration decisions still have to be made with regard to EU law, for example if a court is considering whether to expel someone because of an offence committed when the UK was in the EU.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I skip sections pertaining to EU legislation? If so, which ones?

Like I said in the comment that somebody inexplicably removed, you should read the portions regarding EU legislation, in part because many enactments of UK law originated from EU Directives and Regulations which the UK as [former] member of the European Union had to implement. [This edition](https://books.google.es/books?id=TPd0DgAAQBAJ&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&source=bl&ots=1NXMN0I2Wy&sig=ACfU3U1WKChUhBY53OXw2nzQP9WRXLBW7Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwis8pSi8p3vAhV0olwKHdiUDx4Q6AEwAnoECAsQAw#v=onepage&q&f=false) reflects that reading those portions does not make much difference in terms of pages anyway.

Years of EU legal precedents might have permeated UK case law and/or the UK judiciary's statutory interpretation, and EU laws most likely will keep having an impact on UK law because of the subsequent treaties and agreements both parties foreseeably will sign with each other. Even if the UK Parliament thinks a full legislative dissociation from EU laws is productive, it would take several years for the ensuing repeals and replacements to reach completion.

Furthermore, the acquaintance with EU legislation you would gain from reading those sections is likely to enhance your understanding of UK law. That is because comparisons of two or more systems leads to awareness of aspects (in this case, about UK law) that might otherwise go unnoticed.